# How to debug coredump in lz4 file format in manjaro with lldb?

Tags: c++, linux, clang, lldb, coredump

I'm developing an application with C++14/clang/cmake/lldb toolchain in Manjaro Linux. And it produces some coredumps while testing. For example:

```
$ ls -la /var/lib/systemd/coredump/
core.myapp-test.1000.1faf20db6d6048a18c4b6d28ea2776ee.1973.1590231863000000000000.lz4
```

How could I debug this ? I tried with 2 options:

1. decompress lz4 file and use `lldb -c`.
2. use `coredumpctl debug`.

For option-1:

```
$ sudo unlz4 core.myapp-test.1000.1faf20db6d6048a18c4b6d28ea2776ee.1973.1590231863000000000000.lz4
```

It gives me: `core.myapp-test.1000.1faf20db6d6048a18c4b6d28ea2776ee.1973.1590231863000000000000`.

Then `lldb -c core.myapp-test.1000.1faf20db6d6048a18c4b6d28ea2776ee.1973.1590231863000000000000`.

Then `bt all`, which gives me:

```
(lldb) target create --core "core.myapp-test.1000.1faf20db6d6048a18c4b6d28ea2776ee.1973.1590231863000000000000"
error: Unable to find process plug-in for core file '/var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.myapp-test.1000.1faf20db6d6048a18c4b6d28ea2776ee.1973.1590231863000000000000'
(lldb) bt all
error: invalid process
```

Option-1 failed.

For option-2:

```
$ coredumpctl list
```

It gives me:

```
TIME                            PID   UID   GID SIG COREFILE  EXE
Sat 2020-05-23 19:04:24 CST    1973  1000  1000   6 present   /home/linrongbin/workspace/myapp/debug/test/myapp-test
```

Then: `$coredumpctl debug 1973`

It gives me:

```
...
Failed to invoke gdb: No such file or directory
```

Option-2 failed as well.

So, for option-1, how could I decompressed lz4 coredump successfully and debug it? For option-2, how could I invoke `lldb` in `coredumpctl` ?

Answer (score 4):

I have solved the issue by myself. Use below command will invoke lldb to debug coredump:

```
coredumpctl --debugger=lldb debug 1973
```